# How can I pass Binding<Timer> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, timer, combine

I would like to pass a timer from `ContentView` to `SecondView`, but I don't know how to manage it because I never used it before.

Can someone figure this out for me?

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var timeRemaining = 10
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if timeRemaining > 0 {
                            timeRemaining -= 1
                        }
                    }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView(timer: ???) // <-- What should i pass here?
                } label: {
                    Text("Change View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### SecondView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var timer: ??? // <-- What type?
    @State private var timeRemaining = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if timeRemaining > 0 {
                    timeRemaining -= 1
                }
            }
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView(timer: ???) // <-- Same thing here in SecondView preview
    }
}
```

Comment: There is 2 ways for your issue, first you can pass a string or any other type you need to your needed view, second you can create a class which hold the timer and you use that class as observable object. but as i see in your codes you are not using the timer in your second view, which I think you should focus more in your codes or in your question.

Comment: Don't calculate `timeRemaining` by decrementing an counter. `Timer` isn't very accurate. Store either a starting `Date()` and your timer expires when `timeIntervalSinceNow` returns `<-10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this timer declaration you are in the `Combine` world. `Combine` is the reactive framework from Apple.

First you would need to import it:

```
import Combine
```

I have commented the code but `Combine` is a far field and it probably would be best to read the documentation about it, read some tutorials  and try some things out.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // The typ here is Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>
    // But we can erase it and the result will be a Publisher that emits a date and never throws an error: AnyPublisher<Date,Never>
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    @State private var timeRemaining = 10
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if timeRemaining > 0 {
                            timeRemaining -= 1
                        }
                    }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    // pass the publisher on
                    SecondView(timer: timer)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    //You don´t need binding here as this view never manipulates this publisher
    var timer: AnyPublisher<Date,Never>
    @State private var timeRemaining = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                if timeRemaining > 0 {
                    timeRemaining -= 1
                    print(timeRemaining)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    // Creating a static private var should work here !not tested!
    @State static private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView(timer: timer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine! If i don't bother you, can I ask you if importing Combine will slow down my app? In cases where there is another opportunity, would it be better to avoid using it for simple tasks?

Comment: @userfab No. It doesn´t slow down your app.

Comment: If i need the timer to be every 0.5 seconds and not every 1.0 in my SecondView, what can I do?

Comment: @jooh Then you would need to create a new timer.

Comment: But how to create 2 timers? I tried to create them but when i do it, first one works and second one not

Comment: @jooh I would think that you should ask a new question. This is out of the scope of this one. This is exactly about **not** creating a new timer.

Comment: Ok I will do it, anyway can i contact you somewhere else out of stack to talk about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply inject the timer publisher, as suggested above, but there may be an even simpler solution:

`FirstView` is already updating with every tick of the timer.  You could simply pass a `timeRemaning` binding to your second view and then it too would just update with every tick of the timer (because `timeRemaining` changes on each tick).  You can then observe and react to changes of `timeRemaining` using [.onChange(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onChange(of:perform:)):

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var timeRemaining: TimeInterval

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
           .onChange(of: timeRemaining) {
               if $0 < 0 { 
                   timeRemaining = -1
               }
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I don't need the same timeRemaining, i need the timer to be 10 seconds in ContentView and 5 seconds in SecondView

Comment: Well if it's just a matter of subtraction, then something like timeRemaining - 5 would work.  SecondView could also have as many @state properties as you need if you don't want to modify the parent's state.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass a binding, Since you are not mutating timer of contentview from the second view. You can just pass the reference to the timer publisher and then subscribe to it using `.onReceive()`.

```swift
import Combine // here

struct ContentView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().eraseToAnyPublisher() //<= Here
    @State private var timeRemaining = 10
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if timeRemaining > 0 {
                            timeRemaining -= 1
                        }
                    }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView(timer: timer)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let timer: AnyPublisher<Date, Never> // Here
    @State private var timeRemaining = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if timeRemaining > 0 {
                        timeRemaining -= 1
                    }
                }
            Text("time remaining \(timeRemaining)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i need the timer to be every 0.5 seconds and not every 1.0 in my SecondView, what can I do?

Comment: Its possible , but I would ask this way, do you want to change second view every 0.5 sec ?